# Manganates (II)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ionic-compounds, transition-metals

I want to ask about character of manganese(II) compounds. I read that $\ce{MnO}$ is basic, just like $\ce{Mn(OH)2}$. I started doing research and I read ions like $\ce{MnO2^{2-}}$ and $\ce{HMnO2^-}$ exist too, but how? Are they related to reactions in solid state? Manganese(II) hydroxide isn't amphoteric like aluminium hydroxide so it's really confusing for me. I also found reaction that "confirms" amphoteric character of manganese(II) oxide

$$\ce{Mn(OH)2 + 2NaOH -> Na2[Mn(OH)4]}$$

Comment: Yeah, it is weakly amphoteric. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/zaac.19512640217/abstract;jsessionid=54189D2A000D76548DB237FCE8105623.f03t02

Answer (score 1):

[Manganese(II) hydroxide is **not only a strong base but is also amphoteric** as it dissolves in strong alkali solution to form hydroxomanganates:](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/zaac.19512640217/abstract)

> From the solutions of $\ce{Mn(OH)2}$ in 50% Sodium hydroxide solution,
>   the hydroxometalates $\ce{Na2[Mn(OH)4)}]$ is isolated.

But before forming hydroxomangantes, intermediate ions like $\ce{MnO2^2-}$ and $\ce{HMnO2-}$ are formed. This paper(*) discuss this fact:

> The high solubility of manganese hydroxide in acid solution and its
>   low solubility in alkali solutions give a qualitative indication of
>   the fact that
>   **manganese hydroxide is a strong base**. This seems to be further verified by the observation that manganese salts do not hydrolyze
>   appreciably. The complete verification of this prediction is given in
>   the subsequent calculation of the acidic and basic constants of
>   manganese hydroxide.
>
> The following equations probably indicate the reaction that manganese
>   hydroxide undergoes in water, in acid, and **in alkali**.
>
> (...)
>
> $$\ce{Mn(OH)2(s) + OH- -> HMnO2- + H2O }$$ 
>     $$\ce{Mn(OH)2(s) + 2OH- ->MnO2^2- + 2H2O}$$
>
> (...)
>
> **The Equilibrium in Alkaline Solutions.**
>
> If manganese hydroxide is a strong base then we may expect its
>   hydrogen ion dissociation to be very slight, particularly the second
>   dissociation. Unfortunately, the solubility is so slight in the range
>   where it is possible to calculate these acid dissociation values that
>   no data were obtained.
>
> (...)
>
> $$\ce{Mn(OH)2 -> H+ + HMnO2- K = 1 \times 10^{-19}}$$

*http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01852a001

Comment: No hydroxide can be amphoteric and also a strong base.  If something dissociates hydroxide ions readily, why would it turn around and take in more?